# How to offset circuitikz logic gates so that the input and output ports line up?

Tags: circuitikz, alignment

I want to have a pair of 2-input logic gates placed such that the input of one aligns with the output of the other. It looks like the vertical shift needed is approximately 0.35 × `american xor port/height`.

But where does the 0.35 come from? I've looked at pgfcirctripoles.tex but can't seem to make sense of it.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[americanresistors,americaninductors]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc}
\title{nicelogicpos}
\edef\q{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/american xor port/height}}
\tikzset{
  >=latex,
  every node/.style={font=\sffamily}
}
%\ctikzset{logic ports origin=center}
% doesn't seem to work: I get "I do not know the key '/tikz/logic ports origin'..."

\def\L{1.5cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \a [count=\k] in {31,32,...,37} {
      \node[and port, label={center:0.\a}] (U1) at (0,\k*\L) {};
      \node[xor port] (U2) at ($(0,\a*0.01*\q)+(2cm,\k*\L)$) {};
      \draw [-,red] (U1.out) -| (U2.in 2);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: and how can I make the AND gate label be in the center? I'll ask in a separate question...

Comment: re: gate label in center: never mind, i was using an older version of circuitikz (0.8.something); the `logic ports origin = center` works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I correctly understood your question, than see if the following starting point gives what you after:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[americanresistors,americaninductors]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, 
                positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[and port] (U1) {xxx}; % <---
\node[xor port,right=of U1, anchor=in 2] (U2) {}; % <---
      \draw[red] (U1.out) -- (U2.in 2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This should be easy expand to array of gates as you try to draw in `\foreach` loop.

Comment: ah, the `anchor=in 2` -- got it!

Comment: the `\foreach` was just an example

Comment: ick! the xor gate changed in the newer version to be more pointy. I really wish they would try to match what actually appears in datasheets, which is NOT a pointy stylized XOR gate. Is there a forum for this?

Comment: @JasonS, authors of package are very active members of this site. Just ask question here or even beer make features demand on github site.

Comment: @JasonS `\ctikzset{american or shape=roundy}` will go back to the old shapes. See a recent manual in the "logic port customization" section

Comment: thanks. see https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues/383