# How do you code the following logic gate circuits?

Tags: diagrams, circuitikz, logic, circuits

How do you code the following logic gate diagrams?

[image: Complexity]
[image: Complexity2]
[image: Complexity3]
[image: Complexity4]
[image: Complexity5]

My current attempts:

```
\begin{circuitikz}
        %Top OR Gate
        \draw
        (0,-1) 
        node[label = left:$A$] {}
        to [short]
        (1,-1)
        node[american or port, anchor = in 1] (or1){}
        (or1.in 2)
        -- ++(-1,0)
        node[label = left:$B$] {}
        to[short]
        (or1.in 2)
        (or1.in 2)
        -- ++(-1,0)
        (or1.out)
        to[short] (2.5,-3)
        node[american and port, anchor = in 1] (and1){}
        (and1.in 2)
        -- ++(-2.5,0)
        node[label = left:$C$] {}
        (0,-5) 
        node[label = left:$D$] {}
        to [short]
        (2.5,-5)
        node[american not port, anchor = in 1] (not1){}
        (and1.out)
        to[short] (4,-4)
        node[american or port, anchor = in 1] (or2){}
        (and1.in 2)
        (not1.out)
        to[short] (4, 52 |- or2.in 2)
        (or2.out)
        -- ++(1,0)
        node[label = right:$X$] {}
        %labels
        (or1.out)
        node[label = right:$X_1$] {}
        (and1.out)
        node[label = right:$X_2$] {}
        (xor2.out)
        node[label = right:$X_3$] {}
        \end{circuitikz}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: I am not confident with complex logic gates configurations. But code has been entered as an attempt

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479365/how-to-invert-logic-gate-input-in-circuitikz https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550220/boolean-circuit-using-circuitikz https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/536195/how-to-offset-circuitikz-logic-gates-so-that-the-input-and-output-ports-line-up

Comment: It is much better if you post compilable code (look at my answer). I added a drawing of your code, to make the question more interesting...

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

This is a possible solution; I heavily commented the code to show the reasoning behind it. I do not say this is the only way to do it; but notice that I use explicit coordinates (numbers) only where needed, so changing just one of it will change the spacing of the circuit, keeping it coherent.

```latex
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{circuitikz}
% IEEE standard ports are much nicer
\ctikzset{logic ports=ieee}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % let's start with the first port. The ++(1,0) will select how much to the right
    % from the connection is. Change this to have more space, the rest will follow.
    \draw (0,0) coordinate (start) node[left]{$A$} -- ++(1,0) 
        node[or port, anchor=in 1](or1){} (or1.out) node[right]{$X_1$};
    % second input, below the first one
    % (X -| Y) means: go horizontal from X, vertical from Y
    \draw (or1.in 2) -- (or1.in 2 -| start) node[left]{$B$};
    % the second port will be below and to the right the first one.
    \draw (or1.out) -- ++(0,-1) node[and port, anchor=in 1](and1){}
        (and1.out) node[right]{$X_2$};
    \draw (and1.in 2) -- (and1.in 2 -| start) node[left]{$C$};
    % now, if you really want the not at the same level of and1...
    % we move down for input 2 of and1 without stroking
    \draw (and1.in 2) ++(0,-1) node [not port, anchor=in](not1){}
        % we want the X3 label at the same x-position that X2
        (not1.out -| and1.out) node[right]{$X_3$};
    \draw (not1.in) -- (not1.in -| start) node[left]{$D$};
    % trick here: put the next or midway from and1 and not1
    \draw ($(and1.out)!0.5!(not1.out)$) ++(2,0) node[or port](or2){}
        (or2.out) node[right]{$X$};
    % let do a nice connection here: |- means go vertically then horizontally
    \draw (and1.out) |- (or2.in 1);
    % a little bit trickier for the not, because it's shorter: let's go
    % horizontally  until the above kink, and then |-
    \draw (not1.out) -- (not1.out -| and1.out) |- (or2.in 2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]